# Reminding others of one’s favors for them

Tags: adjectives

What do you call a person who keeps reminding others of one’s favors for them?
When you fight with a person who then keeps telling you I did that I did this for you and so on. I want to tell them that it's inappropriate to remind others of the favors you did for them, especially if I appreciate those favors and try my best to return them.

Comment: How about "an insincere, grudging, score-keeper"?

Answer (score 3):

I'd call them a **scorekeeper**.

A scorekeeper is:

> : a person who records the official score in a game or contest

(Merriam Webster)

However, it's used often in interpersonal arguments.

For example, in this [Art of Manliness article:](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/04/10/beware-the-tit-for-tat-trap/)

> But like all couples, we occasionally have arguments. And a good percentage of them used to be over who was taking care of what, and whether one person wasn’t pulling their weight enough in the relationship.
>
> ...
>
> Couples who fall into The Tit for Tat Trap base their relationships on strict reciprocity. “I will only do this, if you do that. And if you stop doing what I expect of you, I will stop doing what you expect of me.”
>
> ....
>
> All of which is to say: when it comes to accurately **keeping score** in a relationship, we suck.
>
> ....
>
> At this point you might be thinking to yourself, “**Scorekeeping** is something douche-y guys do in a relationship. But not me. In my relationships I’m an incredibly generous and giving guy.”

Google 'scorekeeping -app argument' for more examples.

Comment: A banker? Who else professionally keeps reminding you (of) what you owe them?

(Politically incorrect, perhaps… ?!)

Answer (score -4):

Agree on 'self-interested', 'self-centered' might also be appropriate:

> Concerned solely with one's own desires, needs, or interests